# Why ReduxDevTools doesn't update the cart actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, store

I'm building an ECommerce app with react-redux and I'm implementing the cart actions. I did the same steps with product actions but with cartActions don't update on ReduxDevTools. Is there anything else you think I might be missing?”

***Cart Actions:***

```
   import Axios from 'axios';
import {CART_ADD_ITEM} from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addToCart = (productId,qty) => async (dispatch,getState) =>{
    //generamos una Ajax request al backend con get para traer la info de un producto, await por que espera una respuesta.
    const {data} = await Axios.get(`api/products/${productId}`);
    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.image,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            product: data._id,
            qty,


        },
    });
    
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

***Cart Constants:***

```
export const CART_ADD_ITEM = 'CART_ADD_ITEM';
```

***Cart reducer:***

```
   import {CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants';


export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload;
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
            if (existItem) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
                      x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
                    ),
                  };
                } else {
                  return { ...state, cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item] };
                }
              default:
                return state;
            }
          };
```

***Store:***

```
    import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {cartReducer} from './reducers/cartReducers';
import {productDetailsReducer, productListReducer} from './reducers/productReducers';

const initialState = {
    cart: {
      cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
        : [],
    },
  };
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
});
const composeEnhancer = (typeof window !=='undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__)|| compose;
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
     initialState, 
     composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

***Finally, I have this result in ReduxDevTools:***

[ReduxDevTools results when I try to "AddToCart"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl79n.jpg)

Thank You.

Comment: Show where you are dispatching `addToCart`